# Change the placeholder of login and passcode on alert?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview

I have an alert, and I have 2 text fields on it. I can activate it, but the placeholders are login, and then passcode. I set them, so I want them to be what I set them to.

How is this done?

**CODE:**

```
- (void)newPlaneClicked:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *newPlaneAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"FlightLog Pro" message:@"Enter tail number and make/model:"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil];
    [newPlaneAlert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
    UITextField *enterNewPlaneTail = [[UITextField alloc]init];

    [enterNewPlaneTail setPlaceholder:@"Click to enter a make/model."];
    [[newPlaneAlert textFieldAtIndex:0] setSecureTextEntry:NO];
    enterNewPlaneTail = [newPlaneAlert textFieldAtIndex:0];

    UITextField *enterNewPlaneMM = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    [[newPlaneAlert textFieldAtIndex:1] setSecureTextEntry:NO];

    [enterNewPlaneMM setPlaceholder:@"Click to enter a plane tail number."];
    enterNewPlaneMM.placeholder = @"Click to enter plane tail number.";
    enterNewPlaneMM = [newPlaneAlert textFieldAtIndex:1];
    [newPlaneAlert textFieldAtIndex:0].autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
    [newPlaneAlert textFieldAtIndex:0].autocorrectionType = YES;

    [newPlaneAlert show];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code your assigning `enterNewPlaneTail` and `enterNewPlaneMM` to the alert view's textfields. That's not what you want. You want to assign `enterNewPlaneTail` and `enterNewPlaneMM` from the alert's textfields. Here's how you do that (I cleaned up your code too):

```
UIAlertView *newPlaneAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"FlightLog Pro" message:@"Enter tail number and make/model:"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil];
[newPlaneAlert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];

UITextField *enterNewPlaneTail = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
UITextField *enterNewPlaneMM = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];

[enterNewPlaneTail setPlaceholder:@"Click to enter a make/model."];
[enterNewPlaneMM setPlaceholder:@"Click to enter a plane tail number."];

[newPlaneAlert textFieldAtIndex:0].autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
[newPlaneAlert textFieldAtIndex:0].autocorrectionType = YES;
[newPlaneAlert show];
```